# Select does not keep the value chosen by user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I'm new on Angular, and i'm pretty stuck on a simple select problem.

i did a simple select which iterate my scope to populate the select, but after a user click on an option (which are well created), my select becomes blank with no selection inside, and if i click it again there are no options visible.

below is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.searchFilterDispatcher = {};
$scope.searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'dist1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'dist2'
}];


});
```

```html
<script 
 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<select ng-model="searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode" 
        ng-options="item as (item.label | uppercase) for item in 
 searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode"  
        class="form-control" 
        id="distributionCode">
 <option >{{'SELECT_A_VALUE' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

Any hint?

Comment: check whether you've injected $scope into the controller function or not

Comment: @shahjahan i did it, cause the other scope element work as expected

Comment: @shahjahan that makes absolutely no sense. How would scope model data be being displayed if it wasn't?

Comment: Please provide a working snippet

Comment: You are assigning `ng-model` to same scope property as array source of the options

Comment: @Anon did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your ng-model like following. It works in snippet

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.searchFilterDispatcher = {};
    $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'dist1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'dist2'
    }];
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="val" ng-options="item as (item.label | uppercase) for item in searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode" class="form-control" id="distributionCode">
</select>
</div>
```